# Как работает открытие UserControl через TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `TabControl`:

```
<Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" Grid.Row="1">
    <TabItem Header="buttons">
        <exampleViews:ButtonsExample DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="text">
        <exampleViews:TextExamples DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </TabItem>
```

И есть UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MetroDemo.ExampleViews.ButtonsExample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:MetroDemo="clr-namespace:MetroDemo"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="737.288"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance MetroDemo:MainWindowViewModel}">
```

При нажатии на определённый `TabItem`, открывает нужный `UserControl` на окне. Подскажите, как реализован данный механизм?

P.S. Код взят из репозитория MahApps https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.M...ples/MetroDemo

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, как `TabControl` переключает контент страниц? Как угодно, да хоть через Visibility.

Comment: Не знаю как метро, а WPF табконрол перерисовывает содержимое или делал так раньше, чем сильно удивил

Comment: А как переключить содержимое на UserControl?